# Set Union Notation $A_{\mathbb{N}}$ and question on proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was doing some rudimentary set theory problems to keep sharp and I came across a problem:

Let $A_n=\{(n+1)k|k \in \mathbb{N}\}.$  Find $\bigcup \{A_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

So, is it appropriate to change the notation of $\bigcup \{A_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to $\bigcup A_{\mathbb{N}}?$  It would seem that this should be a reasonable notation and simpler to boot, but I wonder why I haven't come across it before (haven't exactly been looking for it either though...)

Now, onto the proof.  Given a set $A_m=\{(m+1)k|k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, by the Well ordering principle, $A_m$ will have a least element, in particular when $k=1$.  THus, the least element $\forall A_m$ is $m+1.$  Now, let $\alpha_m=m+1$.  Since $\alpha_m \in A_m, \alpha_m \in \bigcup A_m, m=1,2,...$  Now let $S=\{\alpha_m|m \in \mathbb{N}\}$.  This is the set of all least elements of $A_m, m=1,2,...$, so it also has a least element, namely $\alpha_1=1+1=2$.  Thus, since 2 is the least element of least elements in $\bigcup A_m, m=1,2,...$, $\bigcup \{A_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}= \mathbb{N}- \{1\}$.

It seems wordy, but I think I hit all the points.  Is this valid?

EDIT:  I think I need to mention that $S\subseteq \bigcup A_m$

Comment: As for the notation, $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ or even $\bigcup_\Bbb NA_n$ seems more fitting, but $\bigcup A_\Bbb N$ does not. As for your proof... it's hard to understand it. Why not notice that $A_n\subseteq A_1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: But $A_1$ is the even numbers and $A_2$ is the set of multiples of 3, so $A_2$ is not a subset of $A_1$ so I can't make tht argument right?

Comment: Thanks for the help with the notation too! It seemed logical but I understand it is not what is used....

Comment: Ohhh, right. I read it as $(k+1)n$. Sorry... :-) Ignore the second part of my first comment! :-)

Comment: So @Asaf, how does the proof look?

Comment: You don't need the well ordering principle to state that $n+1$ is the least element of $A_n$.  Also, you don't actually need to know that $n+1$ is the least element of $A_n$ for the proof to work.